# CSS view by media screen width

Tags: html, css

I have my CSS file, which looks like this:

```
.topBarBox{
    background-color:black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topBarBox{
     background-color:blue;
  }
}
```

The background color of the `div` is black no matter what the screen size is. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't think its dynamic. If you change your browser-window to smaller than 900px, and refresh the page it will work :-)

Comment: What are you testing it on. It works as given in Chrome.

Comment: @ralph.m Im doing it in Chrome browser. I am hard refreshing the page everytime i change the window size, but doesnt help me :(

Comment: Media queries work as it is, they don't need any refreshing. Are you using any iframes?
Here is JSFiddle example - try to resize window with color square. It acts as it should. https://jsfiddle.net/88puxa4q/

Comment: @SzybkiSasza Nope, I dont

Comment: Create fiddle that will help to know your issue

Comment: I've tried it in edge, IE, Firefox and Chrome worked in all of them.

Comment: @ArunKumarM Well, this tip actually helped me haha. It turned out that It doesnt work when i put `@media...` at the bottom of the css page. When i put it directly below the .topBarBox it works!

Comment: @divHelper11 In that case there is a mistake in your CSS. It should work at any position in your file (after `.topBarBox`, even at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Change your media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px)  {
.topBarBox{
     background-color:blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer :) Unfortunately, it still isn't working. Im hard refreshing the page after changing the browser window size but nothing.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp ckeck out this link, it is not necessary to include "only"

Comment: @ArunKumarM -  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mediaquery

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "only" keyword. 
Change it to this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)  {
.topBarBox {
     background-color:blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer :) Unfortunately, it still isn't working. Im hard refreshing the page after changing the browser window size but nothing.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp ckeck out this link, it is not necessary to include "only"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, your HTML page has following line in your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And also, `<!DOCTYPE html>` above your `<html>` section.

This should work with:

```
.topBarBox{
    background-color:black;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .topBarBox{
     background-color:blue;
  }
}
```

Also, please make sure that either of `html` or `body` does not have any fixed width like:

```
body, html {
   width: 1000px;
}
```

If there is such any CSS style, then remove it or change it like:

```
body, html {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    .topBarBox {
      background-color: black;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
      .topBarBox {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topBarBox">
    Hello
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe you have some styles elsewhere in your CSS that override these styles?

You could try to use the `web-inspector`, that should make things clear.

**Example:**

```css
.topBarBox {
  background-color: black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topBarBox {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topBarBox">
  Hello
</div>
```